# What moves cannot be Sketched by Smeargle?

Tags: pokemon-go

I caught a Smeargle today following a photo bomb with my Lock-On / Focus Blast Registeel. The Smeargle I caught, to my surprise, knew Astonish / Focus Blast, not Lock-On.

Why did Smeargle not Sketch Lock-On, and can this happen to any other moves - in other words, why does Smeargle not Sketch a move? My assumption at the moment is that it cannot learn moves introduced to Pokemon Go after Sketch such as Lock-On, and Transform. However, I couldn't find any information online to support or deny this, and I am somewhat surprised that Niantic didn't make moves introduced after Sketch like Lock-On learnable. It could be a bug.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<sub>Last updated 2021/09/19</sub>

For convenience here is the list of moves Smeargle cannot sketch:

- Feather Dance
- Frustration
- Giga Drain
- Heart Stamp
- Hydro Pump Blastoise
- Leaf Storm
- Mega Drain
- Origin Pulse
- Parabolic Charge
- Precipice Blades
- Razor Shell
- Rest
- Return
- Scald Blastoise
- Transform Fast
- Water Gun Fast Blastoise
- Weather Ball Normal
- Weather Ball Rock
- Wrap Green
- Wrap Pink

I wrote the following Python script to find them from <s>the [`GAME_MASTER.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pokemongo-dev-contrib/pokemongo-game-master/master/versions/latest/GAME_MASTER.json) file in [Jerry's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/371485)</s> the [`GAME_MASTER.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeMiners/game_masters/ea6946f65a15543b7b724034a055e2d46ef8f14d/latest/latest.json) provided by [PokeMiners](https://github.com/PokeMiners/game_masters) via [MBorg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/219593/mborg).

```
import json


def get_templates(data, name):
    return [value["data"][name] for value in data if name in value.get("data", {})]


with open("GAME_MASTER.json") as f:
    templates = json.load(f)

moves = {m["uniqueId"]: m for m in get_templates(templates, "combatMove")}
smeargle_moves = get_templates(templates, "smeargleMovesSettings")[0]

for name, sm in smeargle_moves.items():
    print("removing category: {}".format(name))
    print(sm)
    for move in sm:
        moves.pop(move)

for move in sorted(moves):
    print("-   " + " ".join(map(str.title, move.split("_"))))
```

Comment: I've seen a screenshot of Smeargle having Blaze Kick today. Hence I think the list of Sketchable moves has been updated since this answer as posted.

Comment: Thanks for your quicky reply. Here's a link to a github repository of game_master files https://github.com/PokeMiners/game_masters. By going through the "latest" folder, I found the most recent .json file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeMiners/game_masters/master/latest/latest.json

Comment: @MBorg Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the answer to "What moves **can** be sketched by Smeargle?" is found in the [GAME MASTER](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeMiners/game_masters/master/latest/latest.json) file (from PokeMiners) - search for SMEARGLE_MOVES_SETTINGS.

Finding the moves that Smeargle cannot sketch involves accumulating the entire set of moves, then subtracting the set of moves found above.

Answer (score 3):

To start compiling a list I took a quick glance at the game master files. Here's a list that can be added to as more moves are found to be missing from Smeargle's massive move pool.

Fast Moves:

- Lock-On

Charge Moves:

- Frustration
- Return

Comment: also probably Sketch cuz its the same move and Ditto´s Transform maybe